# Como adicionar varios checkbox em uma tabela com php?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Já vi várias duvidas respondidas parecidas com a  minha mas ate agora nada igual!

É o seguinte: tenho os códigos abaixo e não sei como inserir os `checkbox` na tabela.

Código do formulário

```html
<?php
require "../config.php";
?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>IBVP - Cadastro de Membro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>assets/css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>assets/js/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h2 align="center">Igreja Batista em Vila Permanente</h2>
      <h3 align="center">Cadastrar Membro</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <form method="POST" action="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>membros/add_submit.php">

        <h5 align="center">DADOS PESSOAIS</h5>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Nome Completo" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-2">
            <label class="form-control" style="border: 0;">Data de Nascimento</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dt_nasc" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <select name="est_civil" class="custom-select">
                <option selected>Estado Civil</option>
                <option value="solteiro">Solteiro(a)</option>
                <option value="casado">Casado(a)</option>
                <option value="separado">separado(a)</option>
                <option value="divorciado">Divorciado(a)</option>
                <option value="viuvo">Viúvo(a)</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <select name="sexo" class="custom-select">
                <option selected>Sexo</option>
                <option value="masculino">Masculino</option>
                <option value="feminino">Feminino</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="conjuge" placeholder="Nome do Conjuge" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <label class="form-control" style="border: 0;">Data de Casamento</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dt_casamento" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rg" placeholder="RG" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endereco" placeholder="Endereço" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numero" placeholder="Número" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bairro" placeholder="Bairro" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cidade" placeholder="Cidade" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tel_cel" placeholder="Celular" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tel_res" placeholder="Telefone Residencial" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tel_com" placeholder="Telefone Comercial" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
        </div>

        <h5 align="center">DADOS ECLESIÁSTICOS</h5>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <select name="membro_atraves" class="custom-select">
                <option selected>Tornou-se membro da Igreja através de</option>
                <option value="batismo">Batismo</option>
                <option value="cartaTransferencia">Carta de Transferência</option>
                <option value="aclamacao">Aclamação</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <label class="form-control" style="border: 0;">Data de Recebimento</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dt_membro" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-2">
            <label class="form-control" style="border: 0;">Data de Batismo</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dt_batismo" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="igreja_batismo" placeholder="Igreja que se batizou" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cidade_batismo" placeholder="Cidade" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <h6 align="center">Célula e Discipulado</h6>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <select name="part_cel" class="custom-select">
                <option selected>Participa de Célula Regularmente?</option>
                <option value="sim">Sim</option>
                <option value="nao">Não</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="celula" placeholder="Nome da Célula" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <select name="tem_discipulador" class="custom-select">
                <option selected>Tem Discipulador?</option>
                <option value="sim">Sim</option>
                <option value="nao">Não</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome_discipulador" placeholder="Nome do Discipulador" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <select name="disc_ativo" class="custom-select">
                <option selected>Discipulado Ativo?</option>
                <option value="sim">Sim</option>
                <option value="nao">Não</option>
                <option value="irregular">Irregular</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <h6 align="center">Cursos, Treinamentos e Ministérios</h6>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-check">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="cursos[]" class="form-check-input" value="1" />Curso Pastoral
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="cursos[]"  class="form-check-input" value="2" />C.T.L.
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="cursos[]"  class="form-check-input" value="5" />Encontro com Deus
                                    </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="cursos[homem]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="cursos[]" class="form-check-input" value="6" />Homem ao Máximo
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="cursos[mulher]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="cursos[]" class="form-check-input" value="7" />Mulher Única
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="cursos[crow]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="cursos[]" class="form-check-input" value="8" />CROW
                                    </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <h6 align="center">Cargos e Funções Eclesiásticas Desenvolvidas</h6>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="profebd" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="cargos[profebd]" class="form-check-input" value="profebd" />Professor de EBD
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="louvor" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="cargos[louvor]" class="form-check-input" value="louvor" />Grupo de Louvor, Som ou Mídia
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="evang" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="cargos[evang]" class="form-check-input" value="evang" />Grupo de Visitação ou Evangelismo
                                    </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="lidercong" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="cargos[lidercong]" class="form-check-input" value="lidercong" />Líder de Congregação
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="lidercel" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="cargos[lidercel]" class="form-check-input" value="lidercel" />Líder de Célula
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="outro" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="cargos[outro]" class="form-check-input" value="outro" />Outro
                                    </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <h5 align="center">HABILIDADES PARA SERVIR</h5>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[cozinheira]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[cozinheira]" class="form-check-input" value="cozinheira" />Cozinheira
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[manicure]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[manicure]" class="form-check-input" value="manicure" />Manicure
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[cabelereiro]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[cabelereiro]" class="form-check-input" value="cabelereiro" />Cabelereiro
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[pedreiro]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[pedreiro]" class="form-check-input" value="pedreiro" />Pedreiro
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[eletricista]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[eletricista]" class="form-check-input" value="eletricista" />Eletricista
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[pintor]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[pintor]" class="form-check-input" value="pintor" />Pintor
                                    </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[tecenferm]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[tecenferm]" class="form-check-input" value="tecenferm" />Téc. Enfermagem
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[tecinform]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[tecinform]" class="form-check-input" value="tecinform" />Téc. Informática
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[admcont]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[admcont]" class="form-check-input" value="admcont" />Administrador, Contador
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[advogado]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[advogado]" class="form-check-input" value="advogado" />Advogado
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[artesanato]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[artesanato]" class="form-check-input" value="artesanato" />Artesanato
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[professor]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[professor]" class="form-check-input" value="professor">Professor
                                    </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[engcivileletrico]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[engcivileletrico]" class="form-check-input" value="engcivileletrico" />Engenheiro Civil, Elétrico
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[enfdentmed]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[enfdentmed]" class="form-check-input" value="enfdentmed" />Enfermeiro, Dentista, Médico
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[psicoterapass]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[psicoterapass]" class="form-check-input" value="psicoterapass" />Psicólogo, Terapeuta, Ass. Social
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[musica]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[musica]" class="form-check-input" value="musica" />Música e Artes
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[midiadigital]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[midiadigital]" class="form-check-input" value="midiadigital" />Mídia Digital
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label for="habilidades[outros]" class="form-check-label">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="habilidades[outros]" class="form-check-input" value="outros" />Outros
                                    </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
        </div>


      </form>
    </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

**Código `PHP`:**

```
<?php
require "../config.php";
require "../classes/membro.class.php";



if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $dt_nasc = $_POST['dt_nasc'];
    $est_civil = $_POST['est_civil'];
    $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
    $conjuge = $_POST['conjuge'];
    $dt_casamento = $_POST['dt_casamento'];
    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
    $rg = $_POST['rg'];
    $endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
    $numero = $_POST['numero'];
    $bairro = $_POST['bairro'];
    $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
    $tel_cel = $_POST['tel_cel'];
    $tel_res = $_POST['tel_res'];
    $tel_com = $_POST['tel_com'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $membro_atraves = $_POST['membro_atraves'];
    $dt_membro = $_POST['dt_membro'];
    $dt_batismo = $_POST['dt_batismo'];
    $igreja_batismo = $_POST['igreja_batismo'];
    $cidade_batismo = $_POST['cidade_batismo'];
    $part_cel = $_POST['part_cel'];
    $celula = $_POST['celula'];
    $tem_discipulador = $_POST['tem_discipulador'];
    $nome_discipulador = $_POST['nome_discipulador'];
    $disc_ativo = $_POST['disc_ativo'];
    $cursos = isset($_POST['cursos']);
    $cargos = isset($_POST['cargos']);
    $habilidades = isset($_POST['habilidades']);

    $contato = new Membro();

    $contato->addMembro($nome, $dt_nasc, $est_civil, $sexo, $conjuge, $dt_casamento, $cpf, $rg, $endereco, $numero, $bairro, $cidade, $tel_cel, $tel_res, $tel_com, $email, $membro_atraves, $dt_membro, $dt_batismo, $igreja_batismo, $cidade_batismo, $part_cel, $celula, $tem_discipulador, $nome_discipulador, $disc_ativo, $cursos, $cargos, $habilidades);

    ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>




    <?php
}
?>
  </body>

  </html>
```

**Código da classe:**

```
<?php

class Membro {

    private $pdo;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=siscel;host=localhost", "root", "");
    }

    public function addMembro($nome, $dt_nasc, $est_civil, $sexo, $conjuge, $dt_casamento, $cpf, $rg, $endereco, $numero, $bairro, $cidade, $tel_cel, $tel_res, $tel_com, $email, $membro_atraves, $dt_membro, $dt_batismo, $igreja_batismo, $cidade_batismo, $part_cel, $celula, $tem_discipulador, $nome_discipulador, $disc_ativo, $cursos, $cargos, $habilidades) {

        if($this->existeEmail($email) == false) {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO cad_membro (nome, dt_nasc, est_civil, sexo, conjuge, dt_casamento, cpf, rg, endereco, numero, bairro, cidade, tel_cel, tel_res, tel_com, email, membro_atraves, dt_membro, dt_batismo, igreja_batismo, cidade_batismo, part_cel, celula, tem_discipulador, nome_discipulador, disc_ativo, cursos, cargos, habilidades) VALUES (:nome, :dt_nasc, :est_civil, :sexo, :conjuge, :dt_casamento, :cpf, :rg, :endereco, :numero, :bairro, :cidade, :tel_cel, :tel_res, :tel_com, :email, :membro_atraves, :dt_membro, :dt_batismo, :igreja_batismo, :cidade_batismo, :part_cel, :celula, :tem_discipulador, :nome_discipulador, :disc_ativo, :cursos, :cargos, :habilidades)";

            $sql = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $sql->bindValue(':nome', $nome);
            $sql->bindValue(':dt_nasc', $dt_nasc);
            $sql->bindValue(':est_civil', $est_civil);
            $sql->bindValue(':sexo', $sexo);
            $sql->bindValue(':conjuge', $conjuge);
            $sql->bindValue(':dt_casamento', $dt_casamento);
            $sql->bindValue(':cpf', $cpf);
            $sql->bindValue(':rg', $rg);
            $sql->bindValue(':endereco', $endereco);
            $sql->bindValue(':numero', $numero);
            $sql->bindValue(':bairro', $bairro);
            $sql->bindValue(':cidade', $cidade);
            $sql->bindValue(':tel_cel', $tel_cel);
            $sql->bindValue(':tel_res', $tel_res);
            $sql->bindValue(':tel_com', $tel_com);
            $sql->bindValue(':email', $email);
            $sql->bindValue(':membro_atraves', $membro_atraves);
            $sql->bindValue(':dt_membro', $dt_membro);
            $sql->bindValue(':dt_batismo', $dt_batismo);
            $sql->bindValue(':igreja_batismo', $igreja_batismo);
            $sql->bindValue(':cidade_batismo', $cidade_batismo);
            $sql->bindValue(':part_cel', $part_cel);
            $sql->bindValue(':celula', $celula);
            $sql->bindValue(':tem_discipulador', $tem_discipulador);
            $sql->bindValue(':nome_discipulador', $nome_discipulador);
            $sql->bindValue(':disc_ativo', $disc_ativo);
            $sql->bindValue(':cursos', $cursos);
            $sql->bindValue(':cargos', $cargos);
            $sql->bindValue(':habilidades', $habilidades);
            $sql->execute();

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }

    private function existeEmail($email) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cad_membro WHERE email = :email";
        $sql = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sql->bindValue(':email', $email);
        $sql->execute();

        if($sql->rowCount() > 0) {

            echo "Email para cadastro já existe!";

            return true;
        } else {

            echo "Cadastrado com sucesso!";

            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

**Tabelas:**
 - cad_membro
 - cargos
 - cursos
 - habilidades

Não estou conseguido enviar para a tabela os `checks`.

Comment: Com tudo isso qual o resultado que você tem? O que exatamente está dando errado?

Comment: na tabela cursos independente do que marco ou de quantas marco so aparece o numero 1

Comment: Neste ponto `$sql->bindValue(':cursos', $cursos);` você provavelmente tem um `array` (se quiser ter certeza disso coloque um `var_dump($cursos)` e verá o conteúdo). O que você tem que fazer é percorrer esse `array` para pegar todos os cursos selecionados.
Outra questão é que provavelmente sua tabela esta mal formatada, se os membros podem ter mais de um curso, é necessário ter mais uma tabela para relacionar o membro com os cursos.